# Limpiar un array vacio en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo este array en una `collection` de laravel

```
     0 => array:102 [▼
    0 => "N4G53001275"
    1 => "JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL"
    2 => null
    3 => "GRUPO SALUS"
    4 => "OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO"
    5 => "App Faceit"
    6 => "12:28:30[E] "
    7 => ""
    8 => ""
    9 => ""
    10 => ""
    11 => ""
    12 => ""
    13 => ""
    14 => ""
    15 => ""
    16 => ""
    17 => ""
    18 => ""
    19 => ""
    20 => ""
    21 => ""
    22 => ""
    23 => ""
    24 => ""
    25 => ""
    26 => ""
    27 => ""
    28 => ""
    29 => ""
    30 => ""
    31 => ""
    32 => ""
    33 => ""
    34 => ""
    35 => ""
    36 => ""
    37 => ""
    38 => ""
    39 => ""
    40 => ""
    41 => ""
    42 => ""
    43 => ""
    44 => ""
    45 => ""
    46 => ""
    47 => ""
    48 => ""
    49 => ""
    50 => ""
    51 => ""
    52 => ""
    53 => ""
    54 => ""
    55 => ""
    56 => ""
    57 => ""
    58 => ""
    59 => ""
    60 => ""
    61 => ""
    62 => ""
    63 => ""
    64 => ""
    65 => ""
    66 => ""
    67 => ""
    68 => ""
    69 => ""
    70 => ""
    71 => ""
    72 => ""
    73 => ""
    74 => ""
    75 => ""
    76 => ""
    77 => ""
    78 => ""
    79 => ""
    80 => ""
    81 => ""
    82 => ""
    83 => ""
    84 => ""
    85 => ""
    86 => ""
    87 => ""
    88 => ""
    89 => ""
    90 => ""
    91 => ""
    92 => ""
    93 => ""
    94 => ""
    95 => ""
    96 => ""
    97 => ""
    98 => ""
    99 => ""
    100 => ""
    101 => ""
  ]
  16 => array:102 [▶
    0 => "N4G53001275"
    1 => "JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL"
    2 => null
    3 => "GRUPO SALUS"
    4 => "OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO"
    5 => "App Faceit"
    6 => ""
    7 => ""
    8 => ""
    9 => ""
    10 => ""
    11 => ""
    12 => ""
    13 => ""
    14 => ""
    15 => ""
    16 => ""
    17 => ""
    18 => ""
    19 => ""
    20 => ""
    21 => ""
    22 => ""
    23 => "13:27:12[E] "
    24 => ""
    25 => ""
    26 => ""
    27 => ""
    28 => ""
    29 => ""
    30 => ""
    31 => ""
    32 => ""
    33 => ""
    34 => ""
    35 => ""
    36 => ""
    37 => ""
    38 => ""
    39 => ""
    40 => ""
    41 => ""
    42 => ""
    43 => ""
    44 => ""
    45 => ""
    46 => ""
    47 => ""
    48 => ""
    49 => ""
    50 => ""
    51 => ""
    52 => ""
    53 => ""
    54 => ""
    55 => ""
    56 => ""
    57 => ""
    58 => ""
    59 => ""
    60 => ""
    61 => ""
    62 => ""
    63 => ""
    64 => ""
    65 => ""
    66 => ""
    67 => ""
    68 => ""
    69 => ""
    70 => ""
    71 => ""
    72 => ""
    73 => ""
    74 => ""
    75 => ""
    76 => ""
    77 => ""
    78 => ""
    79 => ""
    80 => ""
    81 => ""
    82 => ""
    83 => ""
    84 => ""
    85 => ""
    86 => ""
    87 => ""
    88 => ""
    89 => ""
    90 => ""
    91 => ""
    92 => ""
    93 => ""
    94 => ""
    95 => ""
    96 => ""
    97 => ""
    98 => ""
    99 => ""
    100 => ""
    101 => ""
  ]];
```

Necesito que me traiga los que si tienen valor sin embargo uso esta funcionalidad y me retorna el mismo valor

```
$users = array_filter($users,  function ($element) {

            if (is_array($element)) {
                if ($key = key($element)) {
                    $element[$key] = array_filter($element);
                }



                if (count($element) != count($element, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
                    $element = array_filter(current($element), __FUNCTION__);
                }

                $element = array_filter($element);

                return $element;
            } else {
                return empty($element) ? false : $element;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que `$users` es un array asociativo y quisieras obtener solamente los elementos con datos en los arrays anidados.

Puedes aplicar `array_filter()` verificando con `strlen`, la cual eliminará los valores que sean: en blanco, `null`, `false`, conservando en cambio el valor `0`. He aplicado también `trim` con `array_map` para limpiar espacios en blanco o no dejar pasar dobles valores en blanco.

Por ejemplo:

```
$users=array(
    array("N4G53001275","JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL",null,"GRUPO SALUS","OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO",
          "App Faceit","12:28:30[E] ","","","","","","","","","","",""," ",false,0));

$cleanUsers=array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $cleanUsers[] = array_filter(array_map('trim',$user), 'strlen');        
}
var_dump($cleanUsers);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "N4G53001275"
    [1]=>
    string(30) "JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "GRUPO SALUS"
    [4]=>
    string(24) "OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO"
    [5]=>
    string(10) "App Faceit"
    [6]=>
    string(11) "12:28:30[E]"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

O, consideremos que pueda haber varios arrays anidados en `$users`:

```
$users=array(
    array("N4G53001275","JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL",null,"GRUPO SALUS","OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO",
          "App Faceit","12:28:30[E] ","","","","","","","","","","",""," ",false,0),
    array("M4G53001275","MJESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL",null,"MGRUPO SALUS","MOFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO",
          "MApp Faceit","12:28:30[E] ","","","","","","","","","","",""," ",false,0),    
    );

$cleanUsers=array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $cleanUsers[] = array_filter(array_map('trim',$user), 'strlen');        
}
var_dump($cleanUsers);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "N4G53001275"
    [1]=>
    string(30) "JESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "GRUPO SALUS"
    [4]=>
    string(24) "OFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO"
    [5]=>
    string(10) "App Faceit"
    [6]=>
    string(11) "12:28:30[E]"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "M4G53001275"
    [1]=>
    string(31) "MJESUS ALEJANDRO LICEA BECERRIL"
    [3]=>
    string(12) "MGRUPO SALUS"
    [4]=>
    string(25) "MOFICINA ESTADO DE MEXICO"
    [5]=>
    string(11) "MApp Faceit"
    [6]=>
    string(11) "12:28:30[E]"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```